# How to copy elements of 2D matrix to 1D array vertically using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, opencv, matrix

I have a 2D matrix and I want to copy its values to a 1D array vertically in an efficient way as the following way.

```
Matrice(3x3)
[1   2   3;
 4   5   6;
 7   8   9]

myarray:
{1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9}
```

Brute force takes 0.25 sec for 1000x750x3 image. I dont want to use vector because I give `myarray` to another function(I didnt write this function) as input. So, is there a c++ or opencv function that I can use? Note that, I'm using opencv library.

Copying matrix to array is also fine, I can first take the transpose of the Mat, then I will copy it to array.

Comment: You can get a pointer to underlying array of a vector with `std::vector.data()` function (or with `&vec[0]`). Just saying.

Comment: There isn't much to optimize here.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: What do you mean? In what way there isn't much to optimize? 
@jrok: Do you mean, I can use vector as array by `&vec[0]`?

Comment: I mean you have "N" distinct numbers which you need to copy. Brute force, for things which need to be copied one by one, isn't actually a pessimistic algorithm. Hence, there isn't "much" to optimize.

Comment: Opencv functions do simple operations(like addition, pairwise min) 30-50 times faster for 1000x750 image than bruteforce. I'm searching for something like that.

Comment: You were asking about copying values from one place to another, not about image processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cv::Mat transposed = myMat.t();
uchar* X = transposed.reshape(1,1).ptr<uchar>(0);
```

or

```
int* X = transposed.reshape(1,1).ptr<int>(0);
```

depending on your matrix type. It might copy data though.

Comment: I've just found out that this is not copying the data, this is just pointing the data location

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize to make it more cache friendly, i.e. you can copy blockwise, keeping track of the positions in myArray, where the data should go to. The point is, that you brute force approach will most likely make each access to the matrix being off-cache, which has a tremendous performance impact. Hence it is better to copy vertical/horizontal taking the cache line size into account.

See the idea bbelow (I didn't test it, so it has most likely bugs, but it should make the idea clear).

```
size_t cachelinesize = 128/sizeof(pixel); // assumed cachelinesize of 128 bytes
struct pixel
{
   char r;
   char g;
   char b;
};
array<array<pixel, 1000>, 750> matrice;
vector<pixel> vec(1000*750);

for (size_t row = 0; row<matrice.size; ++row)
{
    for (size_t col = 0; col<matrice[0].size; col+=cachelinesize)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i<cachelinesize; ++i)
        {
            vec[row*(col+i)]=matrice[row][col+i]; // check here, if right copy order. I didn't test it.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what makes this code more cache friendly? I like the idea of using the cache but I don't get with which lines we acheive to use cache? Thanks, by the way

Comment: the idea is, that you don't do the vertical copy at once but regarding the original matrix to be constructed of "tiles", e.g. one tile with the values [1, 2][4, 5]. Then, when copying the "1", the CPU will load the "2" as well into the cache. Therefore, the column loop has an inner loop the goes from 0 to cachelinesize, making sure, that the "2" (and the "5", etc.) are copied while still in the cache.

Comment: Yes!  Loop interchange and striping are exactly the things to think about to prevent cache-unfriendly access.

Comment: You are only going to see gains from blocking when you operate over the same data and re-use the same block **multiple** times. In this case you are copying only once for each block. I'd be surprised if this yields any speed improvement. The outer middle loop already does the copying in the same order, so it's not clear to me how the inner-most loop ensures that the next element will be loaded for the next copy instruction any different from simply letting the middle loop iterate over the copies.

Comment: You will see it already at the first blockwise copy. The first element access will be off cache, but the other elements in the block are then in the L2/L1 cache and hence the loading of the data will be much faster.

Comment: Yes, but my point is this would already happen without the inner loop. The compiler will optimize this. The inner loop contributes nothing but additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the matrix before the vertical assignment/querying, then you can cache the necessary columns when you hit each one of the elements of columns.

```
 //Multiplies and caches
 doCalcButCacheVerticalsByTheWay(myMatrix,calcType,myMatrix2,cachedColumns); 
 instead of
 doCalc(myMatrix,calcType,myMatrix2); //Multiplies
 then use it like this:
 ...
 tmpVariable=cachedColumns[i];
 ...
```

For example, upper function multiplies the matrix with another one, then when the necessary columns are reached, caching into a temporary array occurs so you can access elements of  it later in a contiguous order.

Comment: Matrix is my image and when I use one row, I use all 1 dimension at a time. I'm dealing with R,G,B at different times. For image that I'm working on now is 1000x750x3 and for a reason I create a 1000x750 double matrix from that image which is around `8x750xK=6 MB` which cannot be put to cache at a time. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Okay, if it doesnt fit in hardware cache, it is still in a contiguous ram space.

Comment: That depends on how many times you will use that array later.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mat::reshape is what you want. It does not copying data.

Comment: You mean, I should, first get the `transpose of matrix`, then `reshape` it, then `copy to myArray`. Is there a shortcut for those process?

Comment: #define ToOneRow(M,arr) arr=M.t();arr=arr.reshape(M.channels(),1); Do you mean something like this? There are no other ways to do this transformation, except using for loop as mentioned above (you can improve it with openMP parallel_for but not on factor above 5, depends on number of processor cores).